# What is the difference between Workflow states vs Types in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, todo, keywords

In org-mode, what is the difference between TODO workflow states and TODO types? They looks and seems the same.

Here's a simple workflow states:

```lisp
     (setq org-todo-keywords
           '((sequence "TODO" "FEEDBACK" "VERIFY" "|" "DONE" "DELEGATED")))
```

And here's a TODO type:

```lisp
     (setq org-todo-keywords '((type "Fred" "Sara" "Lucy" "|" "DONE")))
```

But for me, they both look and function the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [doc](https://orgmode.org/manual/TODO-types.html#TODO-types) says:

> The second possibility is to use TODO keywords to indicate different
> *types* of action items.  For example, you might want to indicate that
> items are for “work” or “home”.  Or, when you work with several people
> on a single project, you might want to assign action items directly to
> persons, by using their names as TODO keywords.  This type of
> functionality is actually much better served by using tags (see *note
> Tags::), so the TODO implementation is kept just for backward
> compatibility.

So you probably should not use `type` at all.